# What is the 'same distribution' mean?

Tags: probability, distributions

Say if I have two random variable X and Y and they have the same distribution, what is that suppose to mean? Is that mean they have same mean and variance?

Comment: If you (arbitrarily) choose any event $E$ (a set of possible outcomes to which we might attribute a probability), then having the same distribution means the chance that $X$ is in $E$ must equal the chance that $Y$ is in $E$, no matter how you chose $E$. Thus, any quantity computed based on chances, including the mean, the variance, and (infinitely many) other things, will be the same for $X$ as it is for $Y$.

Comment: ...and, the *really* amazing thing is, in order to make sure that you have all of that nice structure that @whuber mentions, you only have to check the (comparatively) very simple conditions given in Anderson's answer! :)

Comment: @cardinal Yes, I should have mentioned that. But the impetus for my comment was that I think its characterization better captures the idea of what it really means for two distributions to be the same (and requires less mathematical notation, to boot).  That having equal distribution functions is equivalent to the probabilities of all events being the same amounts to a very useful but logically derivative theorem.

Comment: Looks like your first task is to investigate the simpler question "What is a distribution?"  Perhaps try [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), though that complicates the ideas more than necessary, so try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) instead.

Comment: @whuber I wish that in your first comment, you had called $E$ an _event_ rather than _any set of possible outcomes_ since as you well know, probabilities are defined only for events in the $\sigma$-field, and not necessarily for all possible sets of outcomes. Perhaps as a moderator, you can edit your comment even though it is more than 5 minutes since you posted it?

Comment: @Dilip: I agree (and nearly mentioned it, myself, but "let it slide"), though I suspect the intent of whuber's comment was to try to avoid any overtly mathematical statements in favor of intuition. That said, this is, ultimately, a mathematical question. :-)

Comment: @cardinal I fully agree that whuber's intent was likely to try and avoid overtly mathematical statements, and I don't think it is appropriate to include a definition of event etc in his comment. All I am suggesting is that he amend the comment to say something like "if you arbitrarily choose an event $E$ (set of possible outcomes)..." which makes the statement perfectly correct and yet simple enough that anyone who has never heard of $\sigma$-fields or nonmeasurable sets will be perfectly comfortable with what it is saying.

Comment: @Dilip You and Cardinal are both correct, but I am persuaded by your suggestions and accompanying argument and will change the comment. Thank you both!

Answer (score 10):

It is more general than this. It means that $F_X(t)={\mathbb P}(X\leq t) = {\mathbb P}(Y\leq t) = F_Y(t)$, for all $t$. Then, in particular, if the mean and variance exist, then their values coincide for these variables.

The functions $F_X(t)={\mathbb P}(X\leq t)$ and $F_Y(t)= {\mathbb P}(Y\leq t)$ are termed the *distribution functions* of the variables $X$ and $Y$, respectively.  See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it means that the CDF is the same.

That is, the type of distribution, the mean, the variance, and all parameters are all the same, if they are well-defined.

For most of the commonly seen distributions, like normal distribution, if you can verify that type of distribution and all parameters are the same, then the distributions are the same.

However, be aware of that the mean and variance can be undefined; for example, see Cauchy distribution. In fact, the PDF and any other parameters can be undefinable (credit to Whuber).

However, their correlation can still be arbitrary (or undefined).

Comment: The PDF is superfluous, and so is the reference to parameters.  The *distribution* of a random variable $X$ is given by its probabilities. Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution if and only if for all borel sets $\mathcal B \subset\mathbb R,$ $\Pr(X\in\mathcal B) = \Pr(Y\in\mathcal B).$  When $X$ and $Y$ have the same CDF--whether or not they have a PDF at all--they will have the same distribution. They might not have a mean, either, and their correlation could be undefined if they have no joint distribution.

Comment: @whuber So "no joint distribution" means that the joint distribution can be anything, or does it mean that the joint distribution could be undefinable and non-existence?

Comment: It's the latter: for a correlation coefficient to be defined, $(X,Y)$ must be a bivariate random variable and both $X$ and $Y$ must have finite variances.